# Substituting labels while breaking out for switch case for loop

Tags: go

I submitted a code for review and received a feedback that Labels were error prone

```
ForLoopLabel:
for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
   
    switch i {
    
    case 2 : 
       fmt.Println("hello 2")
       break ForLoopLabel
    
    case 4 :
       fmt.Println("hello 4") 
       break ForLoopLabel
    
    } 
    fmt.Printf("outside case: %d \n", i);
    
}
```

This is a much simplified dumbed down version of my code and was asked to write it without labels.

1. Why are labels error prone?
2. How could I re-write this code without labels? (Assume for loop has hundreds of elements to traverse and cases inside switch statements will only grow with time)

Comment: Your first question is very subjective, labels have their uses like every feature of the language, they just got a bad rep from being misused in other languages. The second: we can just write three print statements, unless you can clarify the problem to solve.

Comment: @Marc I just want to break off from the first time I get a match.

Comment: Add a default case with a continue statement, add a break statement after the switch body. That being said, I'd stick to what you have now. Labeled break statements are not unusual at all, and I wouldn't consider a function with a single label error prone.

Answer (score 0):

I have a different thought that we can apply here ( I am newbie in Go , so, sorry if I am wrong )

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var j int // just used to store case number ( dont know is must )

    //ForLoopLabel:
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {

        i = 4 // Given intenssinaly for testing
        j = i
        switch i {

        case 2:
            fmt.Println("hello 2")
            //break ForLoopLabel
            i = 10

        case 4:
            fmt.Println("hello 4")
            //break ForLoopLabel
            i = 10

        }
        fmt.Printf("outside case: %d \n", j) // Her I used j to get to know which case 

    }
}
```

Here is the [PlayGroundLink](https://play.golang.org/p/m_nxd1NVV_z)

Answer (score -1):

```
a:=[]int{2,4}   
for i:=0;i<len(a);i++{
   fmt.Println("hello ",a[i])
}
```

will do the same thing your code does, the question is why you need to have a switch statement inside a for loop.